# How do I prevent macOS from thinking a folder is a file?

Tags: finder, folders, file-extensions

I am usually copy/pasting the name of the projects my team works on into a folder's name, so that they match.
This allows me to be organized and fast, and to find folders that match project names easily.

However, it doesn't always work, since some project names will have words and some won't.

For example the project that ends in "-lists" was named without an error message, but the second one gave me an error message:

[image]

Now, I need the names of the folders to be as close to project names. Which can contain dots. This way, I can copy the folder name to search the database and find the corresponding project.

But I cannot manually change every single `.` into a `-`, I feel like this would be a lot of trouble.

Should I add the word "folder" at the end to make sure macOS doesn't think my folders have file extensions?

**When does a folder's name turn this folder into a file I won't be able to open anymore, and what are ways to name folders freely, without the system assuming they are extensions?**

Comment: Adding the extension .15 doesn't change the folder into a "file" for me. What application does it try to open when you open the "file"? It's possible that some app has registered a bundle with the extension .15.

Comment: Sorry if that was unclear. It doesn't change the folder to a file, you're right. Although sometimes these changes happen after a restart. The warning message is enough of a disturbance to try to work around it, maybe?

Comment: I feel like the creation date of the folder or file would be enough to justify not adding the full date in the filename in the first place. You can, by the way, set the creation date after the file has been created and set it in the past or the future using [`SetFile`](https://fynydd.com/blog/set-the-creation-and-modification-date-of-a-file-in-os-x-using-the-terminal). That said, it takes a some effort to set up a script or something so you could do it easily. There might be a 3rd party thing (app?) for that. Path Finder does let you change it in the attributes panel. It's well hidden though.

Comment: That suggestion aside, I don't think there would be any objections naming an Alias that way. So a workaround could be to name the folder whatever and make an alias next to it (or wherever) and give it the filename with the date separated by `.`

Comment: I can't think of a specific scenario where this naming scheme for a folder would be problematic, but the `"...folder may appear as a single file"` warning is just that there could be scenarios where it's seen as a file instead of a folder. It's not like you're going to open Finder one day and you can't see them as folders anymore (Unless an OS update changes that). The likely scenario would be like a script or a third party application preventing you from opening the folder _as a folder_, because it sees it as a single file, because folders don't tend to have extensions...or something similar.

Comment: These are all good ideas but you guys are going off into a tangent here. I need the folder name to be identical as the task name in the task management online tool. For if someone points at a 6 month old task in the tool, I can search it by its name which is the name of the folder. The folder is not created on the date it's named after at all, it's the due date of the whole team's project - after I am done working on it. So I copy/paste the project name to create my folders. And I copy the name of the project in a search appto find the corresponding folder in my work archives.

Comment: I'm simply suggesting solutions based on the incomplete information you gave us. Given this new info, you should probably go with my last _tangent_ and ignore the dialog. Use Path Finder (or maybe something else) if you never want to see the warning.

Comment: Didn't mean to hurt your feelings with my comment, I appreciate your comments, they will probably be of great help to people in the future, and they are valid, however for me this is a workflow issue, so the solution I'm looking for needs to fluid, simple and fast to implement.

Answer (score 1):

It’s thinking it has an extension because you’re giving it an [extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension).

Anytime you end something with a `.whatever` you're giving it an extension.  This is a convention across all operating systems and not limited to macOS.

Instead of using dots as a separator for dates, use a dash or an underscore. You don’t  need to do this for all folders all at once, but with a little bash scripting magic and using a utility like `sed` or `awk` the renaming of the files/folders can be done automagically.

Comment: I hear you, I understand how extensions work. Can I add something after the ".15" (say if I really needed to keep ".15") to tell the OS it's a folder? ... ".folder"?

Comment: You can add practically any character with the exception the [reserved characters](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ECN/Support/KB/Docs/ReservedCharactersIn) to the end of the file.  Maybe an underscore (“_”)?

Comment: @Allan all of those characters are allowed in macOS.

Comment: They are reserved which means you *should* not be using them.

Comment: No bash needed: Select all your folders > Right Click > Rename X items... > Replace Text

Comment: Sorry if my comment wasn't clear. After I type ".15" at the end of a folder as part of a date, how do I "disable" it from being identified as an extension, the simplest way? I like the underscore idea, closer to an answer (maybe add it to the answer Allan?). JBis comment blew my mind, I didn't know this feature existed... wonder when it was added.

Comment: You can’t tell macOS to identify something as something else.  Try creating it in terminal.  I create directories like `something.conf.d` as a directory for conf files of a particular app all the time.  Finder may not allow you to create it, but you can do it at the command line.

Comment: Interesting. A bit outside of the scope of what I can implement in my workflow in terms of skills and time consumption. Your first sentence confuses me - adding manually an extension to a file *does* tell macOS to identify it, no? In some cases at least (maybe not for a folder, but definitely for a text file or image).

Comment: Open Terminal, go to the directory you're working in.  For example `cd ~/Documents/foo/bar` to go to the bar sub folder in foo which is in your Documents folder.  Then create a new directory with the command `mkdir foobar.d`. It will be a directory as far as macOS and Finder is concerened.

Comment: [Here's](https://imgur.com/a/gck6lS0) what happened when I add "folder" at the end... The problem still isn't solved.

Comment: Finder (the GUI) see's extensions as being associated with files.  If you need a file like that, create it in Terminal.  However, if you notice - its says "your folder ***may*** appear..."  It's not guaranteed to show up as a file and it further emphasizes the point that this is a Finder convention.